# Where's libmagickwand-6.q16-2-dev?

Tags: imagemagick

I need to make an image with C. For that reason I have to know where is `libmagickwand-dev`.
I read that I need this library (the -`dev` one) to use it in my C program (it's obvious... I just installed all the `libmagick-dev` packages!) but I don't know where is it...

In terminal I've typed `locate libmagick` and the only thing I get is the `/usr/share/doc` stuff.... That's the docs, not the libraries...

Where's it, and if you can, how to call gcc with those options to make my images....

Comment: You are sure you installed `libmagickwand-dev`?  That's a different package than you say you've installed.

Comment: Note that incorporating that library into your C program is outside the scope of this site, as that's a pure programming question that likely belongs on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Yes, I did.
I installed the library libmagickwand-6.q16-2-dev
My question is: Where does ubuntu put the installed package?

Answer (score 0):

You almost did the job in locating it, but instead of typing

```
$ locate libmagick
```

You should have tried

```
$ locate magick
```

The output is:

```
/usr/lib/mime/packages/imagemagick-6.q16
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ImageMagick- 
6.9.7/modules-Q16/coders/magick.la
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ImageMagick- 
6.9.7/modules-Q16/coders/magick.so
...
```

I hope this solves your first problem. But coming to the second I have no idea how it can be done.

sorry for this partial answer.